# Assembly - JZ instruction after CMP

Tags: assembly

I have the next instruction:

```
cmp al, 1
jz mub
```

When al is 2 (10 in binary). What would do this instruction? As I know, I can use JE,JNE,JA etc., but what is meaning jz after cmp instruction?

Thanks

Comment: jz = je, it's the same instruction.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`jz` is "jump if zero". `cmp` subtracts its two operands, and sets flags accordingly. (See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Comparison_Instructions) for reference.)

If the two operands are equal, the subtraction will result in zero and the `ZF` flag will be set.

So in your sample, the jump will be taken if `al` was 1, not taken otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

`jz` means jump if zero. In this context, it will only jump if `al` was 1.

That's because `cmp` is usually equivalent to `sub` (subtract) but without actually changing the value.

`cmp al, 1` will set the processor flags (including the zero flag) based on what would have happened if you'd subtracted 1 from `al`.

If `al` is 2, the jump will not be taken (because the zero flag has not been set) and code will continue to execute at the instruction following the `jz`.

As an aside, `jz` is often the *same* opcode as `je` since they effectively mean the same thing. See for example the [Wikipedia page on x86 control flow](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow):

> **Jump on Zero**
>   `jz loc`
>   Loads EIP with the specified address, if the zero bit is set from a previous arithmetic expression. jz is identical to je.

Answer (score 1):

'Jump Zero' - jump to label 'mub' if the zero flag is set.  'cmp' is a subtract that only sets flags & so, if al is 2, (2-1)<>0 so the zero flag is clear  and the jump will not be performed.